# find major elements appears more than n/3 times

Tags: python, algorithm

Working on below algorithm puzzle and debugging below solution works, for a few test cases. My confusion and question is, how could we always guarantee the count for an elements appears more than n/3 times have a positive count? There are another 2n/3 elements which could make it count negative? But I tried and it always work in my samples. If anyone could help to clarify, it will be great.

Here are the problem statement and my code/test cases,

Given an integer array of size n, find all elements that appear more than ⌊ n/3 ⌋ times. The algorithm should run in linear time and in O(1) space.

```
def majorityElement(nums):
    if not nums:
        return []
    count1, count2, candidate1, candidate2 = 0, 0, 0, 0
    for n in nums:
        if n == candidate1:
            count1 += 1
        elif n == candidate2:
            count2 += 1
        elif count1 == 0:
            candidate1, count1 = n, 1
        elif count2 == 0:
            candidate2, count2 = n, 1
        else:
            count1, count2 = count1 - 1, count2 - 1
    return [n for n in (candidate1, candidate2) if nums.count(n) > len(nums) // 3]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # print majorityElement([1,2,1,3,1,5,6])
    print majorityElement([2,3,1,2,1,3,1,5,5,1,6])
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: I think O(1) space and an O(n) solution is going to be interesting

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, if you have thoughts on my question, it will be greater. You can try my code. :)

Comment: I would use a collections.Counter to get the counts but that will not give you a O(1) space algorithm, I have no idea  how you would satisfy *Given an integer array of size n, find all elements that appear more than ⌊ n/3 ⌋ times. The algorithm should run in linear time and in O(1) space.*

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, thanks. I tried the code I shared works. And just want to understand why it works, and if you could have any thoughts in the future, appreciate for sharing. Have a good day. :)

Comment: Quickselect with a good pivot selection (to ensure O(N) time performance) algorithm should be suitable for modification to your purpose. All you need to do is break up the array into segments of less than about `N/6` in size. If two neighboring pivots have the same value, then the numbers between them also have the same value. So rather than looking for the `kth` item, you are looking for two indices (pivots) that contain `N/3+` of the same element between them.

Comment: @Nuclearman, your solution is not O(1) space complexity? :)

Comment: Ah, forgot to add that it's requires being able to do it in-place (re-arrange the array the holding the input data), which requires no additional memory. Making it `O(1)`. It's far harder to ensure that approach is `O(N)` time than it is to ensure it's `O(1)` space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually, we repeatedly apply a reduction operation to the list that involves deleting three pairwise distinct items. This particular code does reductions online, so that the reduced list so far can be described by two different elements and their corresponding counts (because if there were a third element distinct from the other two, then we could reduce). At the end, we consider at most two elements for occurring more than n/3 times.

The interesting part of the correctness proof is a lemma that, whenever we perform this reduction operation, any element that occurred more n/3 times in the old list occurs more than n'/3 times in the new list, where n is the length of the old list and n' = n-3 is the length of the new list. This ensures by induction that the final list contains all elements occurring more than n/3 times in the initial list (but of course the final list contains only two distinct elements).

The proof of the lemma is that, if an item occurs k times out of n in the old list, then at worst it occurs k-1 times out of n-3 in the new list, and if k/n > 1/3, then

```
              (k-1) n
(k-1)/(n-3) = -------
              (n-3) n

              k (n-3) + 3 k - n
            = -----------------
                   (n-3) n

                      (k/n - 1/3)
            = k/n + 3 -----------
                          n-3

            > 1/3.
```

Comment: Thanks David, what do you mean "deleting three pairwise distinct items"? A bit more details are appreciated.

BTW, my confusion is in the code I posted, it compare with candidate 1 and candidate 2, so should be two items? Why 3? :)

Comment: @LinMa If `count1` and `count2` are positive, and `n` is neither `candidate1` nor `candidate2`, then we delete a `candidate1`, a `candidate2`, and `n`.

Comment: Thanks David, for your comments -- "any element that occurred more n/3 times in the old list occurs more than n'/3 times in the new list, where n is the length of the old list and n' = n-3 is the length of the new list", I read your prove of the lemma and the confusion is I do not find n' (which is the length of the new list)?

Comment: Another confusion is, why n' = n-3 is the length of the new list? The new list should be just 2 elements -- candidate 1 and candidate 2? :)

Comment: @LinMa Ignore the implementation of the algorithm for the moment. Conceptually what it's doing is deleting elements three at a time, e.g., `2,3,1,2,1,3,1,5,5,1,6` (delete `2,3,1`) to `2,1,3,1,5,5,1,6` (delete `2,1,3`) to `1,5,5,1,6` (delete `1,5,6`) to `5,1`, then find that `1` but not `5` appears `>11/3` times.

Comment: Thanks David, smart analysis. My test cases fit into the scenario of delete in a 3-element group perfectly since I create the test case to make 1 distributed sparsely. But suppose in other scenario, if 1 appears a lot in the first half part of the array, but seldom appear in the 2nd part of the array, then how could we ensure it could survive as one of the two candidate in the final? :)

Comment: @LinMa We never delete two 1s at once, so we reach farther and farther into the list to eliminate them. The order actually doesn't matter at all for the analysis.

Comment: Hi David, for sure we delete one 1 at one time. I could be wrong but I think order matters? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. Suppose list like this [1,1,1,1,1,1,...], where "..." means a lot of other elements other than 1. Since number of "..." elements could be as much as 2n/3 - 1, suppose we only have n/3 + 1, I think "..." are good enough to kill all 1s? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @LinMa We're deleting two other elements for every `1` (since we can't delete two `1`s at once), so to kill off `n/3 + 1` ones, we'd need `2n/3 + 2` other elements, which is `n + 3` in total (too many).

Comment: Thanks David, for your comments "deleting two other elements for every 1", want to make sure my understanding is correct, suppose we have candidate 1 and candidate x, with their own counters, and if we met with another candidate y, count of x decrease by one, and y is deleted as well -- and it is what you mean delete two other elements? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa Right -- without that `x` to throw away, we put `y` in the second counter.

Comment: @linma: The proof in this answer is the induction step of a proof by induction (on the number of algorithm steps taken) that a plurality element must be in {candidate1, candidate2} when the list is completely read. Each step of the algorithm maintains the plurality property, and the algorithm terminates with the remaining list containing precisely count1 instances of candidate1 and count2  instances of candidate2. Since plurality elements are preserved by each algorithm step, if there are plurality elements, they must be in this final list.

Comment: @rici, great comments and if you could elaborate a bit more what means "maintains the plurality property", it will be great. What property do you mean specifically?

Comment: @linma: the property that the count for the value is more than n/3. David's very clever proof shows that a deletion step preserves this property. It's clear that a non-deletion step preserves the property because the list is unchanged. So every step of the algorithm preserves the property. So any plurality element (of which there can be at most 2) must survive the entire algorithm until the end. It may appear and disappear from the candidate variables as the algorithm proceeds, but it must be there at the end.

Comment: @LinMa: The thing I find interesting about this particular proof is that it is an example of an induction proof which is not obvious, or even necessarily intuitive. Most of the induction proofs used as examples in elementary math classes are so intuitive that they are boring. But this one is beautifully surprising. (It can be extended to finding elements whose counts are more than n/k for any value of k, using 2k auxiliary memory locations.)

Comment: Thanks @DavidEisenstat for the help, mark as answered. :)

Comment: @rici, appreciate for the great summary. :)